# Look for XML tag value and select the parent which contains the requested tag value

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a lot of XML files which I get via the Google Geo API. I'm interested in the value of the tag **long_name** where the **type** tag contains the value *route*

I can select this value with following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

xml_data = '''
<result>
    <formatted_address>Pariser Platz, 10117 Berlin, Deutschland</formatted_address>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Pariser Platz</long_name>
        <type>route</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Mitte</long_name>
    <type>sublocality_level_1</type>
    </address_component>
</result>
'''

bsObj = bs(xml_data, 'html.parser')

bsObj.find_all('long_name')[1].string
```

Unfortunately the index (in this example the index is 1) of the desired XML Tag changes sometimes so I will not get the route tag every time. So Im looking for a strategy that first looks for the type value route and then select the previous sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the previous `long_name` sibling of the first `type` tag with text equal to `route`, use:

```
long_name_tag = bsObj.find('type', text='route').findPreviousSibling('long_name')
```

Alternatively, to return the text string from the relevant `long_name` tag, use:

```
long_name_tag_text = bsObj.find('type', text='route').findPreviousSibling('long_name').text
```